# Javascript get HTML of selected text nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got the following HTML:

```
<div id="editable_phrase"> 
   <span data-id="42">My</span> 
   <span data-id="43">very</span> 
   <span data-id="1">first</span> 
   <span data-id="21">phrase</span>
</div>
```

and I need to get the `data-id` attributes when I select (highlight) with a mouse these words. I use the following code:

```
var data = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();//this gets the data for all selected words 
console.log(data);
```

It works fine except that when I select last word `phrase`, it selects only text without html contents. Any ideas how to fix that? I can use jQuery.

If I select 2 or 3 words, I need to get their `data-id`s respectively to each word, as it is with `getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()`. The problem is only with the last word, which does not return HTML code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

There has been a similar thread before, here is a working solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/wg1pbwbf/2/

Basically you loop through the siblings in the selection to get each value and then parse the array as string to display it in my result paragraph for better visuals.

**ORIGINAL:**

If you want a jQuery-free version, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hallleron/wg1pbwbf/

The whole Javascript Part is the following:

```
document.getElementById('editable_phrase').addEventListener("click", getDataId);

function getDataId(){
     console.log(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.attributes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

So every time the event listener detects a click, it gets the selected text/span and extracts its `data-id` attribute from the object.

Comment: It select only one element, though I highlight 2 or 3. If I select 3 elements, I need to get all their `data-id`s

Comment: Ah okay sorry I got that wrong... I'll try to update the code as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editable_phrase"> 
    <span data-id="42">My</span> 
    <span data-id="43">very</span> 
    <span data-id="1">first</span> 
    <span data-id="21">phrase</span>
</div>
<script>
    $('#editable_phrase').on('click','span',function(){
        var res = $(this).attr('data-id');
        alert(res);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You could also use `$(this).data("id")`, but I'm not sure which is faster.

Comment: Are you not going to say why that helps or is it a secret?

Comment: Does it work with selection? If I select (highlight) 3 words in a row I need to get their 3 `data-id`s